# Mysql Join Union Query By Date

Tags: mysql, database, select, join, union

I have 2 tables 
and i want the result as this using join query. I don't have any Idea
[Join Query By](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5BAyk.jpg)

```
TBL_SUCCESS_ORDER
------------------------
id |    date    | amount
-------------------------
 1 | 2017-01-01 | 1000
 2 | 2017-01-06 |  300
 3 | 2017-01-29 |   50
 4 | 2017-02-02 |  100
 5 | 2017-02-16 |  400
 6 | 2017-03-01 |  500
 7 | 2017-04-03 | 1200



TBL_FAIL_ORDER
------------------------
id |    date    | amount
-------------------------
 1 | 2017-01-03 |  400
 2 | 2017-01-07 |  300
 3 | 2017-01-24 |   50
 4 | 2017-02-02 |  100
 5 | 2017-04-07 |  200


RESULT
------------------------------------------------------------------
year |   month | sum_of_succes_amount | sum_of_fail_amount | total
------------------------------------------------------------------
2017 | January |                 1350 |                750 |  2100
2017 | Febuary |                  500 |                100 |   600
2017 |   March |                  500 |                  0 |   500
2017 |   April |                 1200 |                200 |  1400
```

I been stack for a whole week i did not  get it . When i connect api json

```
TBL_PENDING_ORDER
------------------------
id |    date    | amount
-------------------------
 1 | 2017-04-03 |  600
 2 | 2017-05-07 |  600

RESULT
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
year |   month | sum_of_succes_amount | sum_of_fail_amount | sum_of_pending_amount |total
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2017 | January |                 1350 |                750 |                     0 | 2100
2017 | Febuary |                  500 |                100 |                     0 |  600
2017 |   March |                  500 |                  0 |                     0 |  500
2017 |   April |                 1200 |                200 |                   600 | 2000
2017 |     May |                    0 |                  0 |                   600 |  600
```

What if I add The third table ? TBL_PENDING_ORDER

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Then blah blah blah

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following solution using `UNION ALL` AND `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT 
    YEAR(x.date), 
    MONTH(x.date), 
    SUM(CASE WHEN x.type = 'S' THEN amount ELSE 0 END) AS sum_of_succes_amount,
    SUM(CASE WHEN x.type = 'F' THEN amount ELSE 0 END) AS sum_of_fail_amount,
    SUM(amount) AS total 
FROM (
    SELECT id, date, amount, 'S' AS type FROM TBL_SUCCESS_ORDER
    UNION ALL
    SELECT id, date, amount, 'F' AS type FROM TBL_FAIL_ORDER
)x GROUP BY YEAR(x.date), MONTH(x.date)
```

**You want to add the third table `TBL_PENDING_ORDER`?**

```
SELECT 
    YEAR(x.date), 
    MONTH(x.date), 
    SUM(CASE WHEN x.type = 'S' THEN amount ELSE 0 END) AS sum_of_succes_amount,
    SUM(CASE WHEN x.type = 'F' THEN amount ELSE 0 END) AS sum_of_fail_amount,
    SUM(CASE WHEN x.type = 'P' THEN amount ELSE 0 END) AS sum_of_pending_amount,
    SUM(amount) AS total 
FROM (
    SELECT id, date, amount, 'S' AS type FROM TBL_SUCCESS_ORDER
    UNION ALL
    SELECT id, date, amount, 'F' AS type FROM TBL_FAIL_ORDER
    UNION ALL
    SELECT id, date, amount, 'P' AS type FROM TBL_PENDING_ORDER
)x GROUP BY YEAR(x.date), MONTH(x.date)
```

Comment: so nice you save my day ... How about if add 3rd table which is the TBL_PENDING_ORDER its same format of two table ...